# ASP.Net Membership: List Roles in Listbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-roles

I'm trying to put together a custom user update page so you can update a user's email, password and role all on one page. I'm stuck on the roles. I have listed the roles ok, but I want to select the role allocated to the user in a listbox.

In this case each user will only have one role.

I've tried playing around with `Roles.GetRolesForUser("userName");` without much luck.

Here's the listbox code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="myRoles" runat="server"
     SelectionMode="Single" >
</asp:ListBox>
```

And here's the databinding for the Listbox:

```
rolesArray = Roles.GetAllRoles();
myRoles.DataSource = rolesArray;
myRoles.DataBind();
```

What's the easiest to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var allRoles = new[] {"Admin", "Client", "Super Admin", "Other"};

        //Returns string array
        var rolesByUser = Roles.GetRolesForUser(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

        myRoles.DataSource = allRoles;
        myRoles.DataBind();

        foreach (ListItem role in myRoles.Items)
        {
            foreach (var userRole in rolesByUser)
            {
                if (role.Text == userRole)
                    role.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your html:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="myRoles" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

### Single Role/Single Selection Only

Change loop to :

```
foreach (ListItem role in myRoles.Items)
        {
            if (role.Text == rolesByUser.FirstOrDefault())
                role.Selected = true;
        }
```

### Alternatives

Here's a shorter version of that loop using LINQ to Objects:

```
    foreach (ListItem role in myRoles.Items)
            {
                foreach (var userRole in rolesByUser
                                    .Where(userRole => role.Text == userRole))
                {
                    role.Selected = true;
                }
            }
```

And finally a pure LINQ mode that is in my opinion a bit too hard to read:

```
foreach (ListItem role in from ListItem role in myRoles.Items 
                from userRole in rolesByUser.Where(userRole => role.Text == userRole) 
                select role)
        {
            role.Selected = true;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Nick, Sorry for the slow reply and thank you for providing a straight forward answer. I've tried getting this to work but I've not had any luck in returning Roles for the User. I've replaced `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` with `Roles.GetRolesForUser("Current.UserName")` as I'm using `string userName = Request.QueryString["UN"].ToString();              MembershipUser Current = myuser[userName];` to get the username from a list on a previous page. `foreach (var userRole in rolesByUser)` is not looping. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I know why. The user isn't logged in. But I wanted to highlight a role for a selected user from a list of users, not the one currently logged in. This is for a intranet where only administrators will have access to user accounts. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This fixed it Nick: `foreach (ListItem role in AvailableRoles.Items)
                {
                    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Current.UserName, role.Text)) 
                    {
                        role.Selected = true;
                    }
                }` Thanks for your help